# C# - Prevent TopMost Form from Overriding Main App Title

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main Winforms application with a title of "My Application". When that main form loads, it creates another form that will hover at the top of the screen:

```
Form hoverForm = new Form();
hoverForm.Text = "HoverForm";
hoverForm.TopMost = true;
hoverForm.Top = 0;
hoverForm.Show();
```

This works fine:

[image]

...but I've noticed that when I see any references to the process title (e.g. attaching a debugger), I see the title of that topmost form instead of the parent form.

[image: Screenshot showing overridden Title]

Is there any way to preserve the "float-on-top-of-everything-else" behavior without it overriding the process title? I've tried things like AddOwnedForm() but no luck.

Comment: What happens if you delay creating the hover form until slightly later? I suspect the title comes from the first form created, and perhaps you're creating the hover form before the main form completes its initialization.

Comment: I've moved the creation/initialization of the hover form to a button click to test that, but I see the same result.

Comment: The "process title" is quite irrelevant, it is just an aid to help a programmer pick the correct process to debug.  Possibly useful when multiple instances of the process are currently running.  Move on, you don't need to fix this.

Comment: @HansPassant - The debugger and the above application are just an example. The -real- application is an enterprise product and I'm building a plugin for it that adds the hovering form. However, there are other utilities/applications that will search for certain instances of the real application based on keywords within the process title. When my plugin's topmost form overrides the process title, it breaks these other utilities/applications, which is why I need a fix for it.

Comment: There is no formal definition of a "process title" in Windows.  So it is not guessable exactly what those other "utilities/applications" look for.  The Process.MainWindowTitle property is notable, it has to guess what the main window might be.  Windows has no way to say "this is my main window".  It uses a basic heuristic, it enumerates the windows owned by the process and simply picks the first one.  Which tends to be the first window that was created by the app, modulo complications due to a splash or login window.

Comment: Also look at the taskbar buttons created for these windows.  One of them probably ought to have its ShowInTaskbar property set to False.  The [AssemblyTitle] attribute may play a role, less likely in a plugin.